# Pandas calculate days elapsed and percent change

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with a hierarchical index (ID & Date) and measure M.
I would like to add two new measures to my df; the first would be percent change of measure M from the prior observation and the second would be days elapsed.
All within the "window" of ID (i.e. the first observation within each ID would be zero for both new measures)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to group by ID, get the differences you want and sew together a new dataframe. Suggestions on how to do this better and/or in place are welcome.

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
grouped = your_df.groupby('ID')
for grp_id in grouped.groups:
    grp = grouped.get_group(grp_id)
    grp["diff"] = np.concatenate([np.array([0]),np.diff(grp['M'].values)]) # get the    differences of M
    grp["days_elapsed"] = np.concatenate([np.array([None]),days_elapsed(grp.index.values)]) #

    new_df = new_df.append(grp)
```

And the function to get the elapsed days from a pandas TimeIndex:

```
def days_elapsed(l):
res= []
print l
for x in range(1,len(l)):

    res.append((l[x]-l[x-1])/np.timedelta64(1, 'D'))

return res
```